# how to integrate an png image with html imagemap in gwt app

Tags: image, gwt, imagemap

my gwt app uses an external lib to render charts (birt). this lib is able to provide an html/js-imagamap with the rendered png.
but what is the best way to integrate it in gwt front-end? my first idea was to let the lib generate html with imagemap and embedded (base64) image. the html could be easily integrated?!

but base64 is noot good for ie6/7 (ie8 max 32kb). so is there a way to link the image in html and write an servlet/gwt-service to fetch image on loading the html? or is ther a much easier way?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the html+js/css generated, why not just render that as an iframe in your main app? its simple and effective.

Comment: how to do this with gwt? and as i mentioned how to do this without using an embedded image?

Comment: you create a servlet that serves the html+png assets. Then in your gwt code, you create an iframe, and set the frame's source to point to the servlet.

Comment: thx in meantime i got similar answer elsewhere: without data uri 2 requests are necessary: the first one gets the map (html) and the second one requests the image. but an iframe isn't necessary.